# programming windows phone 8 app compared to iOS and Android

Tags: android, iphone, ios, windows

I have developed and ported my apps for iOS and Android. In my experience porting from iOS to Android or vice versa is quite straight forward in most cases. The main extra effort so far always came from certain specialities like Widgets for Android, Notifications, WIFI vs BT communication, server communication, etc.... Even UI is quite easy to port.

Now I am thinking about WP 8. In your experience how does this compare to iOS/Android development?
I do not have any real Windows 8 insight yet. Is it closer to iOS or Android - if one can tell ?
Is the learning experience and speed similar to coming from iOS <-> Android ?

I am not asking for an estimate of compared development effort as this depends on too many specialities - I know! (however would be interesting to hear about some experiences)

I am more interested if there is any "better" more efficient approach to Windows 8 app development - coming from iOS or Android?

Many thanks

Comment: Porting apps from one platform to another will result in an app that looks very out-of-place on the target platform.  You should always re-design the UI.

Comment: @SLaks muchos +1s for that. Would an xbox game feel right on a wii?

Comment: @SLaks, ...and he must convert every line of code from `Objective C` to `.NET` compatible, and the whole structure of the application from `MVC` to `MVVM`, so... I guess, it will be pure pleasure for him.

Comment: @holex: How different is that from Java <-> Objective-C?

Comment: @SLaks, are you asking it really or it is just your sarcasm?

Comment: @holex: I've never done any iPhone or Android development.

Comment: @SLaks, oh sorry I didn't know it. the `Java` and `Objective C` have a same logic and both of them implement the `MVC` pattern. this is why the conversion is relatively easy because you don't need to make different documentation, the only thing what you have to do is the implementing the methods in the selected language, according the docs. the `.NET` platform works with the `MVVM` pattern and you might design a different application structure because the logic of the `MVC` pattern is not usable for it.

Comment: I see.  Note that .Net itself has nothing to do with MVVM; it is XAML and the Win8 UI framework that encourage MVVM.

Comment: @SLaks, but shortly the main difference is between the `MVC` and `MVVM` pattern.

Comment: @SLaks, the `MCV` and `MVVM` are architectural patterns, the `XAML` is a kind of markup language - like oranges vs. submarines. they don't have too much relationship between each other as far as I know.

Comment: @holex: Yes, but the way XAML is used with the UI framework (especially bindings) encourages MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SLaks said, you have to redesign the UI to respect the UI guidelines of the platform.

However, on Windows 8, you can create your app with HTML5/CSS/Javascript, or with XAML/C#

I think in your case the most interesting way to make the portage is using the second solution. Maybe you'll be able to port some of your Java code to C#

Also, keep in mind that Windows 8 is PC and tablet system. So it's very different from Android/IOS in many ways.